How can I exclude rows where the description contains a phrase, but only if it is referenced once?
I have to create a dataset of our email logs to find responses to our prize competition. Our email log is very poor, so I am limited in how I can identify records we are interested in.
We only want it to be included if it has the word 'prizedraw' in it. However, we don't want it to be included if the record has the phrase 'you have been entered in our prizedraw'...unless there is another occurrence of the word 'prizedraw' in the email chain.
I'm struggling to come up with a viable solution for this, has anyone got any ideas?
An example of what I'm hoping to keep in the dataset is where the email log is someone responding to the email saying 'you have been entered in our prizedraw' saying 'I didn't enter this prizedraw'. This would all be in one email chain so would all be on one row in the emaildescription column.
Tried using where emaildescription like '%prizedraw%'and not like '%you have been entered in our prizedraw%' but this excludes email chains where a second appearance of prizedraw appears

Maybe something like: where replace(message, 'you have been entered in our prizedraw', '') like '%prizedraw%' ?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

This is a little sketchy, but it's one way to solve the problem. You can determine the count of each of these phrases by using len() and replace() and then comparing the counts to see if your condition is hit. More info at this answer on how len() and replace() can be used to get a count of a specific substring
WHERE (len(email_col) - len(replace(email_col, 'you have been entered in our prizedraw', '')))/38 < (len(email_col) - len(replace(email_col, 'prizedraw', '')))/9

Probably some tweaking is needed to avoid div/0 type errors, but I think the logic is sound.
dbfiddle example here
This would be relatively simple task with regex, but I believe that regex support in sql-server is pretty limited.

Apparently MS is adding regex support to Azure SQL DB  (if they haven't renamed it again).  Down in the comments the author says it will be available a in a future release of SQL Server.  https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sql/introducing-regular-expression-regex-support-in-azure-sql-db/

I was under the impression that Azure had regex support already. A negative look-behind would make short work of this in a REGEXP_LIKE().

Wouldn't WHERE replace(email_col, 'you have been entered in our prizedraw', '') LIKE '%prizedraw%' be simpler and avoid having to think about div/0?

Azure does have regex support but this is still gated by signing up for a preview (not GA yet)
